# Get all table tr data in single HtmlNodeCollection c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need to retrieve all `tr` from all tables using HTML Agility Pack.

HTML:

```
<section class="content-section" id="more">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h2>Specs</h2>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr><th colspan="2"> test</th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                         
                            <tr><td>2</td><td>b</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>                                    
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>3</td><td>c</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>4</td><td>d</td></tr>               
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>  
</section>
```

C#:

```
HtmlNodeCollection featuresNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='more']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr");
```

I am only able to get first table `tr` but not getting all two table `tr` in `HtmlNodeCollection`.

Comment: I got 4 `tr` nodes when trying your code. Isn't it correct?

Comment: @krlzlx  please check updated html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all `tr` nodes including the one in `thead`, update your `XPath` to:

```
"//*[@id='more']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/table//tr"
```

This simplified `XPath` should also work:

```
"//*[@id='more']//tr"
```

If you want only the `tr` from `tbody`, use:

```
"//*[@id='more']//tbody//tr"
```

Or excluding `tr` from `thead`, use:

```
"//*[@id='more']//tr[not(ancestor::thead)]"
```

Comment: I got the all tr but its possible to not include the thead tr ?

Comment: @AnupPatil: See my update. But if that's what you want, your XPath works too: `"//*[@id='more']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr"`

Comment: @AnupPatil: Great! Glad that I could help you.